# why it result in a NullPointerException when Object is null?

Tags: java

when objec is null:

```
if(object != null && object.string.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("no error");
}
```

it will result in NullPointerException, and why if it checks the first result is false, it still check the second instead of stop check and print "no error"? 
sorry for my bad english -_-#

Comment: What if `object.string` is null?

Comment: I think Java isn't using a lazy evaluation like some other languages, it will check to whole condition before choosing the answer true/false.

Comment: object.string can be null

Comment: @Lutzi it is using lazy eval here.

Comment: @Lutzi The `&&` operator _is_ short-circuiting (i.e. lazy). But an 'AND' condition will evaluate the second half if the first half is true. That's what it means.

Comment: && only evaluates the right side if the left side is true.  Very clearly defined in the JLS.

Comment: @Lutzi No. `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting operators just as in C++ and C and Lisp where the McCarthy operators came from in the first place.

Comment: @nbrooks Thanks for the precision ! So `&&` and `AND` are not equivalent ? Sorry for my bad comment, but it's really a pleasure to interact with other Java programmers ! I'll try to check my answer better than that.

Answer (score 3):

It's not `object` which is `null` but `object.string`.

Try: `(object != null && "".equals(object.string))`

Comment: thank you, and I find my mistake : before I take a judgement, I'm already Obeject object = new Obeject(); thank you for your answer again